# iZotope RX 2 audio engine specs

Tags: izotope

Hi everybody,

Does the standalone version of iZotope RX 2 have more resolution than the audio suite plugins? Do you know what is the resolution of the audio engine in both cases?

Cheers,
Elena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by resolution? Sample rate? Sample rates are universal.

> Does the standalone version of iZotope
>   RX 2 have more resolution than the
>   audio suite plugins?

No. If it would, it would've been specified.

Comment: i was thinking about the audio engine resolution, which of both gives better results?

Comment: What's "audio engine resolution"? The both give the same results, although the standalone version can enable more CPU-intensive settings (e.g. for more precise noise reduction).